# JavaFX - Package Misete not found in module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Hello im using IntelliJ IDEA and im making some JavaFX app but now its gives me error

i did my VM option is : `--module-path "C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\openjfx-16_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-16\lib;C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Code\production" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

but its still gives me this error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Code\production\Misete
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package Misete not found in module
```

and module-info.java :

```java
module Misete {
    requires java.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires java.desktop;

    opens Misete to javafx.graphics;
}
```

("Misete" is my project name)

Comment: `opens … to` is expecting a *package* name. Is there a package called `Misete` in your module? (Specifically here you probably need to open the package containing your `Application` subclass to `javafx.graphics`.)